# How to make a function available to the command `parallel` (GNU)?

Tags: bash, shell, function, parallelism

In Bash, let's consider a function that does nothing but `echo` the argument followed by "is an integer".

```
f () { num="${!1}"; echo $num is an integer; }
number=12
f number
# 12 is an integer
```

I would like to write on a file a number of commands that uses the function `f` and then run these commands in parallel using the function `parallel` (GNU).

```
# Write Commands to the file `Commands.txt`
rm Commands.txt
touch Commands.txt
for i in $(seq 1 5)
do
   echo "number=$i; f number" >> Commands.txt
done
```

With `source` everything work fine

```
source Commands.txt
1 is an integer
2 is an integer
3 is an integer
4 is an integer
5 is an integer
```

However, when I try to run the commands in parallel it returns that the function `f` is not found

```
parallel :::: Commands.txt
/bin/bash: f: command not found
/bin/bash: f: command not found
/bin/bash: f: command not found
/bin/bash: f: command not found
/bin/bash: f: command not found
```

Is there a way I can make my function `f` available for `parallel` without having to define the function at each line of the file `Commands.txt`?

Answer (score 6):

You basically have three options:

1. `export -f` (which is a non-POSIX bash feature)
2. Execute a shell defining the function on each invocation
3. Move the function to a shell script and run that instead

Option 1 is probably the easiest to demonstrate, so I'll show that one:

```
$ f() { num=$1; echo "$num is an integer"; }
$ export -f f
$ cat Commands.txt 
number=1; f "$number" 
number=2; f "$number" 
number=3; f "$number" 
number=4; f "$number" 
number=5; f "$number" 
$ parallel :::: Commands.txt
1 is an integer
2 is an integer
3 is an integer
4 is an integer
5 is an integer
```

Note that your population of `Commands.txt` is likely in error, you need `f "$number"` in `Commands.txt` to pass the number, not `f number` which would pass the literal string "number". Your script to generate it should do `echo "number=$i; f \"\$number\""` (note the escapes, which are important to avoid `$number` being interpreted at `echo` time, or the `"`s terminating the string).

Comment: Option 4: use env_parallel (described in `man parallel`) and use that to export the whole environment.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Sure, but judging from the OPs expected output, it seems they want `${1}`, not `${!1}`.

Answer (score 2):

Bash can export functions through environment variables.

```
export -f f
```

Note that this is a bash feature, not available in other shells of the sh family.

Alternatively, make the function a script. Scripts and functions have the same syntax apart from the function definition line.

```
#!/bin/bash
num="${!1}"; echo $num is an integer;
```

If you do that, you'll need to export the variable you pass to the script: the lines in `Command.txt` will need to look like

```
export number=1; f number
```

or

```
number=1 f number
```